# Detect if browser supports jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, modernizr, feature-detection, mobile-browser

How do I detect if the browser supports [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)?

I was thinking in using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com) but I don't know which features to detect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/about/platforms.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

  [$.mobile.gradeA()](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/globalconfig.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the browser grade.

```
if($.mobile.gradeA()){
   alert("Supports");
}else{
   alert("Does not support");
}
```